# Clean Retina Theme #Wordpress, How do I delete the header and footer background pattern?

Tags: css, wordpress

In the theme options it says that in order to show my back ground in the header and footer that I need to add my own CSS which basically ignores,or prioritizes my background (which is already displayed in the "content part" or middle of the website) over there default pattern. I have very basic coding skills. Any help is appreciated. (Note: I'm not trying to change the color, I want to ignore the default pattern background and I want my background to display across the whole website) Nutivet.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to style.css in your theme folder and at line 453 you will find the css for "branding" this  is the id for your header:

```
 #branding{
     background: url("images/header-bg.jpg");
 ....
 }
```

Change it to your pattern.
Or change it to none:

```
  background: none;
```

The id for your footer is colophon.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just to clarify I was trying to hide the default background from my header and footer. Thank you @DincăAlexandru <br> To Clarify I used >#branding{
     background: none;
 }
#colophon{
     background: none;
}

Comment: Glad to help! You should consider changing the color of your font to make it easier to read, now that you have an image as a background.

Comment: LOL That's my next challenge, The theme doesn't make it easy to change the font color so I guess it's time to go hunting through code. Thanks again.

Comment: Use chrome or firefox with the firebug plugin. Right click on the text you want changed, then select inspect element. You will now open the developer tools, and on the right side you will see the css for the text you have inspected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's going to make life a little easier. :)